# User permissions for frame buffer

Tags: permissions, framebuffer

Trying to write something to frame buffer:

```
cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb0
```

Got error:

```
bash: /dev/fb0: Permission denied
```

How to allow my current user to write to frame buffer?

Comment: If it is 14.04 it is long past EOL and totally off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add user to the video group

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

You should also run the command from tty

There is this great post about it.
http://seenaburns.com/2018/04/04/writing-to-the-framebuffer/

P.S. To apply new settings you should log out and log in or just reboot.